# how to set purchase limit on certain items per user for one year time period in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi in WooCommerce I have one condition for products, i.e. products have custom field purchase limit with Yes/No options. Here once user logged into purchase an item if that item comes under purchase limit (Yes), then I want to check one condition as if the user already purchased that product in last 30 days, want to display error message you already purchased this item and disable the "add to cart" button. If that user not purchased that product in last 30 days, can able to add to cart that product.

I used below code but it is not working...

```
 /*** Hide "Add to Cart" button for purchased products and show 
 custom message.
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 
'hide_add_to_cart_for_purchased_products', 10, 2 );
 function hide_add_to_cart_for_purchased_products( $is_purchasable, 
$product ) {
// Check if user is logged in
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    // Check if user has already purchased the product
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $args = array(
        'customer_id' => $user_id,
        'status'      => array( 'wc-completed' ),
        'limit'       => -1,
        'return'      => 'ids',
        'meta_key'    => '_product_id',
        'meta_value'  => $product_id,
    );
    $order_ids = wc_get_orders( $args );
    
    if ( ! empty( $order_ids ) ) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
        
        // Display custom message
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_custom_message_for_purchased_products', 35 );
        function display_custom_message_for_purchased_products() {
            echo '<p class="purchased-message">' . __( "You have already purchased this product.", "woocommerce" ) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information and especially some code to your post that we can review. Where exactly is the problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: i have updated my code, but it is not working. please provide solution

Comment: The problem above is that orders are not stored with items as `meta_key => meta_value`. Items are stored in a different table which you can reach with `$order->get_items()`, see in the solution already posted by @businessbloomer

Answer (score 1):

In the title you said you want to limit it to 1 item/year, while in the description you mentioned 1 item/30 days.

I actually have a similar [solution for limiting the overall daily product stock](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-limit-sales-per-day/), so here's a revised version that should work in case you want to limit it to 1 purchase / 30 days for a single logged-in customer (you did not say how your custom field is called, so I'm using a placeholder. Please change accordingly):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'bbloomer_not_purchasable_after_daily_limit', 9999, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_not_purchasable_after_daily_limit( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
         
   if ( get_current_user_id() == 0 ) return $is_purchasable; 

   if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_whatever_custom_field', true ) == 'No' ) return $is_purchasable;
    
   // GET LAST 30 DAYS ORDERS FOR LOGGED IN CUSTOMER
   $all_orders = wc_get_orders(
      array(
         'limit' => -1,
         'date_created' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-30 days' ) ),
         'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
         'return' => 'ids',
      )
   );
   $count = 0;
   foreach ( $all_orders as $all_order ) {
      $order = wc_get_order( $all_order );
      $items = $order->get_items();
      foreach ( $items as $item ) {
         $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
         if ( $product_id == $product->get_id() ) {
            $count = $count + absint( $item['qty'] ); 
         }
      }
   }
    
   // LIMIT 1 SALE
   if ( $count >= 1 ) return false;
    
   return $is_purchasable;
    
}
```

This would simply hide the Add to Cart message and deny any purchase to the logged in customer for a given product they already purchased in the last 30 days.

If you also want to show a notice, I guess on the single product page, you can use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_display_message_if_not_purchasable_single_product', 20 );

function bbloomer_display_message_if_not_purchasable_single_product() {
    global $product;    
    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        echo '<p>You already purchased this product in the last 30 days</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: by using above code not getting current user orders

Comment: `if ( get_current_user_id() > 0 ) return $is_purchasable;` is the opposite of what you want to achieve. You should replace it with `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $is_purchasable;`